# How to make a post request when it has a @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following tables in my database: **RoleModel** and **UserModel**. The UserModel table has a **@ManyToMany** relationship with RoleModel, where a user can be assigned one or more roles. How should I pass the role_id in the POST request body when registering a user?

**UserModel**

```
public class UserModel {

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<RoleModel> roles;
}
```

**RoleModel**

```
public class RoleModel {

    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleName roleName;
```

**UserDtoRequest** Here is my problem!

```
public class UserDtoRequest {
    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<Long> roleModelIds;

}
```

I tried to assemble the request this way in the POSTMAN.

```
{
    "username": "joao",
    "password": "test",
    "roleModelId": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a @RequestParam annotation for passing a parameter which is not related to the same entity class in this case.
I am adding a code snippet. you can take a reference from it.

```
@PostMapping("/users")public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user, @RequestParam("role_ids") String roleIds) {
        user.setId(0);
        userservice.saveUser(user, roleIds);
        return "blog saved";
}
```

You'll need to separate the roleIds and convert it to integer or long in the service layer before saving it.